# How many $N$-isogeny maps s.t. given kernel of $N'$ multiplication

Tags: elliptic-curves, isogeny

Sorry for my bad English.

Let $p$ be a prime number,
$N'>N$ be coprime positive integer and
$f:E_1\to E_2$ be a degree $N$ separable isogeny map between elliptic curves (if necessary supersingular).

When given  basis $P,Q\in E_1[N']$ and the image $f(P), f(Q)$, how many $N$-isogenies $g:E_1\to E_2$ are there with $g(P)=f(P)$ and $g(Q)=f(Q)$?

By assumption there is at least example $f=g$, but when $g$ is uniquely determined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A sufficient condition for the isogeny $g$ to be uniquely defined is given by $N'^2 < 4N$, see Sec. 4 of [1].

That is because if $f$ and $g$ are distinct isogenies that agree on the same torsion images, then $E_1[N'] \subset \ker(f - g)$, which means $\deg(f- g) > N'^2$.
At the same time, you have $\deg(f-g) < 4N$ by Lemma V.1.2 of Silverman's *Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves*.

[1]: C. Martindale and L. Panny, How to not break SIDH, https://eprint.iacr.org/2019/558.pdf